# Selecting multiple elements within a jquery template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am trying to change the class of one or more elements within a template when a button is clicked.  The samples I have ssen all usually find one item with .tmplItem, and I can't quite figure out how to achieve what I'm trying to do.  This is more or less a proof of concept.

i have a structure like below.

```
var messages = [
{ Body: "Testing 1", Read: "0" },
{ Body: "Testing 2", Read: "1" },
{ Body: "Testing 3", Read: "0" },
{ Body: "Testing 4", Read: "1" }
];
```

my template is:

```
    <script id="messageTemplate" type="text/html">
        {{if Read == "1"}}
        <tr class="hdnMessage">
            <td class="hdnMessage" >
<input type="checkbox" id="cbHasReadMessage" checked="checked">
</td>
        {{else}}
        <tr class="showMessage">
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="cbHasReadMessage"></td>
        {{/if}}        
        <td>${Body}</td>
        </tr>
</script>
```

css is:

```
<style type="text/css">
.hdnMessage 
{
    display:none;
}
.showMessage
{
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

I have a button outside of the template

```
<input type="button" value="Show Read Messages" id="btnShowHideReadMessages" />
```

which I added a click event for:

```
$("#btnShowHideReadMessages").click(function() {    
if (showingReadMessages) {
      showingReadMessages = false;
      $(this).val("Show Read Messages");
//try to find checked checkboxes and set the class of the tr which is its parent
}    
else {
      showingReadMessages = true;
      ///Try finding all the current hidden TRs
      var hdnMessages = $("tr.hdnMessage").tmplItem();
      var hdnMsg = hdnMessages.data;
      var hdnElement = hdnMessages.nodes;
      $(hdnElement).replaceWith($('.showMessage'));
      }    
});
```

The last script segment is incomplete as I couldnt figure out how to get this to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are setting each and every checkbox as `id="cbHasReadMessage"`, which isn't allowed. Change the ID to a class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I am so use to letting .net name my row level checkboxes I forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `class="showMessage"` from the template altogether then change the bottom section of code to something like this:

```
$("#btnShowHideReadMessages").click(function() {  
     $("tr.hdnMessage").toggleClass('hdnMessage');
});
```

Comment: Doesnt appear to work.  I get an error that the object doesnt support that method.  Since the tr is in the template would you be able to reference the tr like this?  I also noticed Im setting a td to hide.  Im going to check to see if that may be the issue.

Comment: This did work. the syntax is $("tr.hdnMessage").toggleClass('hdnMessage');

Comment: If anyone was interested in the showing and hiding mechanism, I did the following:   $("#btnShowHideReadMessages").click(function() {
     if (showingReadMessages) {
     showingReadMessages = false;
     $(this).attr('value', 'Show Read Messages'); 
     $("input.cbMessage:checked").parent().parent().toggleClass('hdnMessage');
     }
     else {
     showingReadMessages = true;
     $(this).attr('value', 'Hide Read Messages');
     $("tr.hdnMessage").toggleClass('hdnMessage');
     }
    });